# front end logo upload like happytables

Tags: admin, front-end

[happytables](http://happytables.com) has a cool feature where if you are logged in, on the home page && haven't uploaded a logo yet it will insert a drag + drop image box similar to image uploader on the backend.

any ideas on how to pull this off? currently digging thru the source code, but if anyone has some pointers, i'd greatly appreciate it --

Comment: Do you have a link to this actually happening in the wild?

Comment: You need to be logged in to view it, but here's a *wild* screenshot: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0074t7861

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually wrote this for Happy Tables so should be able to give you a couple of pointers, though I don't have time to go into too much depth at the moment.

We use this "image well" on tables tables a fair bit, it's basically the drag/drop upload from the WordPress upload. Similar to something like this: https://github.com/tobiasnygren/Drag-Drop-for-Post-Thumbnails we use Plupload for the image well, which send the file to the WordPress media-upload.php.

Anyway, this is all open source from Happy Tables which you can view here: https://github.com/themeforce/framework/blob/master/core_options/tf.options-of-uploader.php

It is pretty modular, so you might be able to use it as is pretty much. It does lean on WP Thumb, which you can download here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-thumb/

Comment: Just discovered the themeforce framework - what an incredible resource! many thanks for this answer!